# jQuery event Attributes

Tags: html, jquery

I want to know the clear difference between `delegateTarget` and `currentTarget` keys of jQuery event object.

```
  $(this).on('click',function(event){
       console.log(event.delegateTarget);
       console.log(event.currentTarget);
   })
```

both are looking very similar
which one should use?
thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will notice a difference when using event delegation.

Here's a better example to illustrate

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'button', function(event) {
    console.log(event.delegateTarget); // body
    console.log(event.currentTarget); // button
});​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PRcte/1/ and http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events